# Browser bottom scrollbar doesn't show

Tags: html, css

I made a web page. When I zoom it, there is no scroll bar on the bottom of browser. I tried many times but I can't.

Please any body help me.

Here is my dropbox [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/239482200/New%20folder/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Hi now **remove** to your `.fix` in **css** `overflow:hidden;` and **add this css** in your **stylesheet**

**as like this**

**Remove this css**

```
.fix {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Add this css**

```
.fix{
  *zoom: 1;
}
.fix:after, .fix:before {
content: "";
display: table;
line-height: 0;
}

.fix:after {
clear: both;
}
```

**Your Css Path is**

```
css/main.css  ---> Line No is 111
```